# Why do positron generators use solenoid magnets to focus positrons instead of FODO structures?

Tags: accelerator-physics

When positrons are generated from a particle beam hitting a dense target, why do we use solenoid electromagnets to focus the resulting positrons? As far as I can see, a FODO  (focus-open-defocus-open, focus means quadrupoles focus on x plane, but defocus on y plane) array of quadrupole magnets can focus them, too.

Comment: Hi Alex, Welcome to Physics.S.E. Please make your question clearer than it stands. This way users would know what you know and what you need help with. Thanks,

Comment: Who is "we", at which accelerator and beam line and to which purpose?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 1):

Solenoid magnets can focus in both the X and Y planes, unlike quadrupoles. They are also simpler devices that don't require the precise alignment that a FODO array would require. The limitation on solenoid magnets is that they are only effective at focusing low-energy beams, like the positrons from your spallation source or primary electrons after being emitted from a cathode.

Comment: Thanks for answering.How about high energy beam produced by laser,which may product positrons of hundreds of MeV?Will FODO array help to focus such beam?

Comment: I haven't done the calculations, but from what I've seen in labs, solenoid magnets are only used close to the guns and accelerating cavities. After acceleration, it's all quadrupole magnets, even for 100-MeV electron beams.